# ExtJS 4.2.0 error: Layout run failed

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, bryntum-scheduler

I am using the Bryntum Scheduler v 2.2.5 with Exts JS 4.2.0
I have added the diagnostic tools and the console output is below.

I am using a Sch.panel.SchedulerTree.
Is this diagnostic telling me I need to set a width 
for the SchedulerTree SchedulerGrid headercontainer columns?

```
==================== LAYOUT ==================== 
[E] Layout run failed
[E] ----------------- FAILURE -----------------
 --schedulergridview-1036<tableview> - size: calculated/calculated 
      triggeredBy: count=1 
         headercontainer-1035.columnWidthsDone () dirty: false, setBy: ? 
Cycles: 2, Flushes: 0, Calculates: 1 in 2 msec 
Calculates by type: 
tableview: 1 in 1 tries (1x) at 0 msec (avg 0 msec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
schedulerConfig{ layout: 'auto'}
```

to my 'Sch.panel.SchedulerTree' and my 'Layout run failed' error is gone!